# Create an alarm clock on lock screen

Tags: android, alarmmanager, lockscreenwidget

I would like to make my own alarm clock app, but I can't figure out how to display an activity on top of the lock screen - like the alarm screen [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nzFXCdMGlgT3YgdurdCeTaU-ffHRSiTA/view).

Even after some research, I have no idea what I should use to accomplish this.
If you have any clue on how to do this or what to use please let me know.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.com! Please make your question a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make your post answerable.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but u can check wakeLock on event when it fire but i don't know how it behavior with locked screen. I work on current app and using partical for my procesor let collecting data for sensors and work great. Meybe try that with option screenBright